# Negiah before Nisuin

Tags: halacha, yibbum-chalitza-levirate, negia, kiddushin-eirusin

Unless I'm mistaken, after a non-ervah goes to the mikvah, affectionate touch would at most be prohibited rabbinically. I assume here it is prohibited rabbinically. If so, there are two cases I am wondering about:

1. Arusa, after kiddushin before nisuin does this prohibition apply? Chazal [forbade](https://www.sefaria.org/Tractate_Kallah.1.1) yichud with one's arusa, so I'm wondering if negiah also applies
2. Shomeres Yavam, someone's husband died childless and are now expected to do yibum or chalitzah with his brother. Is the potential yavam forbidden from affectionate touch with his shomeres yavam before yibum? If so, I would imagine it would make yibum slightly more difficult/awkward, unless for some reason it is permitted while one is in the process of performing yibum

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72659/discussion-on-question-by-robev-negiah-before-nisuin).

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84259/touching-a-niddah-other-than-ones-wife

Comment: "in the process of performing yibum" similarly perhaps when one is in the yichud room

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if there's no prohibition touching a *penuya tehorah*<sup>1</sup> (single girl), these two cases have some sources which could indicate an issur.

**Arusa**

That very passage in *masseches kalla* states without *sheva brachos* a *kallah* is אסורה כנדה and this is quoted by Shu"t HaGeonim Shaarei Tzedek (4:4:24), Rashi Kesubos (7b) and many other sources.

It is forbidden to touch one's wife who is a *nidda*, as Rambam writes in Issurei Biah ([11:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Forbidden_Intercourse.11.19)).

Accordingly, the Chida writes in his commentary to *masseches kalla* there that it is forbidden to touch a *kalla* like a *nidda*:

> כלה בלא ברכה אסורה כלומר אפי' לחבק **או ליגע בה** כנדה.

So according to him there is prohibition to touch your *arusah*.

However, it should be noted that the simple reading of *masseches kalla* isnt that she is actually like a *nidda*, but just that although she is your wife, relations with her are prohibited.That is the natural reading of the continuation:

> מה נדה שלא טבלה אסורה לבעלה, אף כלה בלא ברכה אסורה לבעלה

There is no evidence that the particulars of *hilchos nidda* apply to her. Indeed, R. Aurbach of T'veria is quoted in the article: הוראות והערות הרב שלמה זלמן אוירבך בדיני חופה ונשואין printed in מבקשי תורה כז, תשס"ב, יב - טו that it obviously doesn't mean that they have the same laws<sup>2</sup>:

> הדבר פשוט ואין צריך לפנים שאין בכלה בלא ברכה דיני הרחקות אף שכ' ואסורה לבעלה כנדה.

Also, a noteworthy comment of the Rambam sheds light on what he thinks is the significance of the comparison to *nidda*

> תשובת  הרמב"ם סימן רפח
>
> וכלה בלא ברכה אסורה לבעלה מדרבנן וזה שאמרו כנדה לחזק הדבר בלבד

We see he felt *Chazal* used this expression to show how serious their prohibition should be viewed.

**Shomeres yavam**

Regarding a *shomeres yavam*, one important source potentially indicating a problem touching her, is the Yerushalmi Yevamos (1:1) regarding the practice of R. Yossi ben Chalafta who performed the act of *yibbum* through a sheet. While there is much discussion about this passage, some, such as Korban Ha'Edah there, connect this to the view of Abba Shaul (Yevamos 39b) that intent for *yibbbum* must be pure since otherwise the children are like *mamzerim*. Rambam explains (Bechoros 1:7) that in his view, the *shomeres yavam* retains characteristics of erva, and is therefore only permitted through *yibbum* alone. Similarly, Maharshal implies in Yam Shel Sh'lomo to Yevamos (4:2) that R. Yossi's behavior was related to the *erva* status of a sister in law that *yevama* carries.

This would be a source to prohibit non-*yibbum* contact that would be forbidden with other *arayos* (classically hugging or kissing and other such contact).

It should be noted that there are many reasons why *halacha* would nevertheless not follow this.

Credits to an anonymous scholar who provided me with the sources.

---

<sup>1</sup> Interestingly, regarding touching brides, the Sefer Maharil ‏(מנהגים) הלכות נישואין writes:

> והחתן תופש אותה בידו

The groom holds her hand. He was speaking on the day of the wedding, before the *kiddushin*

<sup>2</sup> However, the following in the *Sefer* [Shalmei Simcha](https://books.google.ca/books/about/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%94.html?id=mma2ZwEACAAJ&redir_esc=y) pg. 186 implies Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach himself held she does have *harchokos* like a *niddah*.

> יש נוהגין שהחתן לא ימסור לכלה את כוס הברכה מידו לידה, כיון דהוי אחר האירוסין, וכלה בלא ברכה אסורה לבעלה כנדה. ורבינו אמר שזה אינו ובודאי מן הראוי שהחתן יתן לכלה. ואין בזה כל חשש, שהרי הכוס של אירוסין הוא לפני אירוסין, ועדיין איננו "כלה" בלא ברכה, והכוס של נישואין אף דהוי אחר קידושין לפני הנישואין דהיינו לפני ייחוד, אין בזה כל חשש, ששתי חומרות הן, א. שיטת הר"מ שמצריך גם ייחוד. ב. חומרא דהושטה מיד ליד כשיטת רש"י.‏

Perhaps this is just *derech pilpul* but not to imply she's really like a *niddah*. I subsequently saw the source of Rav Auerbach of Tiveria inside and realized he was directly commenting on this source. He says like I thought on this statement of his father:

> ודברי אאמו"ר זצ"ל נאמרו בדרך מו"מ של הלכה בלבד דממנ"פ אין לאסור, אבל לא נתכוין לדייק מדבריו שיהיה החתן אסור לאחוז ביד הכלה בלכתם לחדר יחוד.

Comment: +1 Notably if we really treated an Arusa like a Niddah then there would always be a problem of passing the bride her ring and her Ketubbah

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe you're right about the kesubah, but the ring is before kiddushin. It's even permissible to give the ring to a woman who is mamash a niddah. Seemingly no one would say there are harchakos before she's an arusa. The Chida could be saying there is afterwards, which is unusual. Maybe he held the chasan doesn't pass the kesubah to his arusah. Maybe through a shliach?

Comment: Many hold the husband tosses her the ring and doesn't put it on her hand if she is a Niddah.

Comment: @robev I looked up that Rambam and the posuk you cite doesn't say "it is forbidden to touch a niddah."

Comment: @SAH there the Rambam [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Forbidden_Intercourse.11.19): ולא יגע בבשרה. What posuk?

Comment: @robev But in context, he's talking about a niddah who is one's wife. No?

Comment: @SAH well, this whole question is about one's wife. But I'll clarify. Thanks.

Comment: @robev I thought it was about one's arusa?

Comment: @SAH arusa = wife...?

Comment: @robev I thought there was no hutra yet by an arusa

Comment: @SAH what hutra

Comment: @robev Sorry. There is no nisuin. (?)

Comment: @SAH correct. I still don't understand your question. Arusa is defined as an אשת איש no less than a nesuah...there are unrelated differences between them but that doesn't detract from my quote of the Rambam.